# Newbie problem with cron and server_start.sh

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron, steam, games

I decided to put my Valheim Dedicated Server to my second computer which is running on Xfce desktop environment. I got it running fine and and decided to try using cron first time. I made bash file that closes the server and reboots the computer and it is running fine on cron. After that I wanted cron to start my server by using start_server.sh file which I'm at this moment using via terminal to start up the Valheim server. I tried to do it with @reboot but it doesn't seem to work at all. I'd assume it has something to do how the server_start.sh works, since I checked it has all the rights and so on.

Here is the crontab I made for this:

```
#Set the hardware clock to keep it in sync with the more accurate system clock.
55 07 * * * /sbin/hwclock --systohc

#Run restnboot.sh that closes Valheim server and restarts computer.
50 08 * * * /home/restnreboot.sh

#Starts Valheim server at reboot.
@reboot sleep 240 && /home/X/steamcmd/start_server.sh
```

I also tried to add #!/bin/sh in to the sh file. Here is the start_server.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
export templdpath=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./linux64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export SteamAppId=892970

echo "Starting server PRESS CTRL-C to exit"

./valheim_server.x86_64 -name "name" -port 2456 -world "name" -password "password" -nographics -batchmode -public 1

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$templdpath
```

If anyone has any idea what I should do next, that would be appreciated. Thanks for your time!

Comment: IMHO what you should do next is redirect the cron job's output and errors to a log file ex. append `>/home/X/steamcmd/start_server.log 2>&1` or `>/home/X/steamcmd/start_server.log 2>/home/X/steamcmd/start_server.err` which you can then examine for causes of failure. At a *guess*, the issue will turn out to be the use of *relative paths* for `./valheim_server.x86_64` and `./linux64`

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Yes the problem was what you said, I tried what you wrote and found from the log that execution was missing valheim_server.x86_64. I got it working with adding cd /home/x/steamcmd to the command line.Not sure if it is the best solution, but as I said I'm very new to linux and I don't quite understand how pathings work yet : P.